# Capturing drawing from Nativescript Angular with nativescript-drawingpad

Tags: nativescript-angular

I'm attempting to capture drawings for an app using the native-script drawingpad plugin. I'm working (among other things) from the helpful tutorial provided here:
[Capturing Signatures with NativeScript + Angular](http://tylerablake.com/nativescript/2019/05/02/capturing-signatures.html)

My component includes the following:

```html
    <GridLayout rows="*,auto" columns="*" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF">

        <StackLayout col="0" row="0" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF">
            <Label [visibility]="signatureImage ? 'visible' : 'collapsed'" text="Preview" textWrap="true" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center"></Label>
            <Image [visibility]="signatureImage ? 'visible' : 'collapsed'" [src]="signatureImage" height="150" width="90%" borderColor="black" borderWidth="2"></Image>

            <Label text="Sign/Update below" textWrap="true" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center" marginTop="20"></Label>

            <DrawingPad #DrawingPad backgroundcolor="#FEFEFE" height="150" width="90%" id="drawingPad" penColor="#FF6B6B" penWidth="3" borderColor="black"
                        borderWidth="2">
            </DrawingPad>
        </StackLayout>

        <GridLayout col="0" row="1" rows="auto,*" columns="*,*">
            <Button col="0" row="0" colSpan="2" text="Clear Signature" (tap)="clearMyDrawing()"></Button>


            <Button col="1" row="1" class="btn -primary" text="Save" (tap)="onDoneTap()"></Button>
        </GridLayout>

    </GridLayout>
```

In the TS I have the following:

```js
    onDoneTap(): void {
        // get reference to the drawing pad
        const pad = this.DrawingPad.nativeElement;

        // then get the drawing (Bitmap on Android) of the drawingpad
        let drawingImage;
        pad.getDrawing().then(
            (data) => {
              console.log(data);
                drawingImage = data;
                this.signatureImageString = imageSourceModule.fromNativeSource(data).toBase64String("png");
                //this.driverSvc.storeSignature(this.DRNO, this.signatureImageString,null,null,null);
            },
            (err) => {
              console.log(err);
            }
        );

      }
```

Running the application produces the following error at the console:

```
    CONSOLE LOG file: src/app/deliveries/signatures/signatures.component.ts:43:22: <UIImage:0x280feb060 anonymous {729, 150}>
    CONSOLE LOG file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/image-source/image-source.ios.js:344:0: fromNativeSource() is deprecated. Use ImageSource constructor instead.
```

Then it crashes.

Unfortunately the documents as far as I can see do not indicate that fromNativeSource() is deprecated. I need to be able to either 1) save the image as a file to subsequently upload, or 2) save the image as a base64 string for subsequent upload.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it this way solved the problem:

```
  onDoneTap(): void {
// get reference to the drawing pad
const pad = this.DrawingPad.nativeElement;

// then get the drawing (Bitmap on Android) of the drawingpad
pad.getDrawing().then(
    ( data) => {
          const source = new imageSourceModule.ImageSource;
          source.setNativeSource(data);
          this.signatureImageString = source.toBase64String("png");
        })
```

}